# removed python(3?) and and now desktop won't load

Tags: kubuntu, python, desktop-environments

I was having some issues with python on my kubuntu 21.10 (for so reason apt installed it to home rather than usr, which meant it wasn't on the path and I couldn't import any modules I pip installed.

To fix this, I tried to remove python using apt. This promptly broke the desktop and moved me to a terminal screen but with no input. Now if I try to boot into desktop my system just hangs on manufacture (Acer swift 3) logo.

Is there a workaround (could I try installing the kubuntu desktop from the recovery terminal) or should I just reinstall kubuntu? I'm on kubuntu 21.10.

Thanks.

Comment: Virtually everything in Ubuntu runs on Python.  You may have to reinstall the OS to recover here.

Comment: I have answered how to recover the desktop. If you have a question about setting up a python environment, please ask a new one. Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: There are more than 100 similar questions about removing python3 in this forum. You should've searched before you got yourself in such a mess. Removing python3 is like taking the pistons out of a car motor

Comment: You may find `apt` doesn't work too... as if you removed the default python; everything that requires python will stop working...  Basic tools may work; ie. `wget` to download packages & `dpkg` to install, but higher end user tools (like `apt`) tend to need python. You'll need `python3-minimal` installed to have `apt` and `apt-get` work even at text terminal (text terminal doesn't require python so can be used even though you've crippled your GUI)

Comment: Apologies I think I was being in too specific in my search and so had not returned the duplicate questions. Thanks for the help @ArchismanPanigrahi, I have edited the question to remove the additional tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run Ubuntu without Python.

---

Open a virtual TTY console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, and login.

Connect to internet with USB tethering from your phone.

Install the Kubuntu desktop. It should install all the necessary components including python.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop^
```

If it does not work, you will have to reinstall.

**When you remove something in the terminal, you should always check which packages are being removed.**